# Linux - How to overclock ATI Radeon GPU - Sapphire R9 270

Tags: linux, amd-radeon, overclocking

I have a Sapphire R9 270 ([exact model](http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/?cid=1&gid=3&sgid=1227&pid=2089&psn=&lid=1&leg=0)), I've read this can be overclocked to a similar speed to the 270x. How can I achieve this under Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `amdconfig` tool that comes with the AMD Drivers. If you do `amdconfig --help` you'll get something like:

```
AMD Overdrive (TM) options:
  The following options are used to get and set current and peak, core
  and memory clock information as well as read the current temperature of
  adapters.  By using the "--adapter=" argument the AMD Overdrive (TM)
  options can be targeted to a particular adapter in a multi-adapter scenario.
  If no adapter is explicitly targeted the commands will be run on the Default
  adapter as indicated by the "--list-adapters" command

  --od-enable
        Unlocks the ability to change core or memory clock values by
        acknowledging that you have read and understood the AMD Overdrive (TM)
        disclaimer and accept responsibility for and recognize the potential
        dangers posed to your hardware by changing the default core or memory
        clocks

  --od-disable
        Disables AMD Overdrive(TM) set related aticonfig options.  Previously
        commited core and memory clock values will remain, but will not be set
        on X Server restart.

  --odgc, --od-getclocks
        Lists various information regarding current core and memory clock
        settings.
        Including: current and peak clocks
                   the theoretical range clocks can be set to
                   the current load on the GPU

  --odsc, --od-setclocks={NewCoreClock|0,NewMemoryClock|0}
        Sets the core and memory clock to the values specified in MHz
        The new clock values must be within the theoretical ranges provided
        by --od-getclocks.  If a 0 is passed as either the NewCoreClock or
        NewMemoryClock it will retain the previous value and not be changed.
        There is no guarantee that the attempted clock values will succeed
        even if they lay inside the theoretical range.  These newly set
        clock values will revert to the default values if they are not
        committed using the "--od-commitclocks" command before X is
        restarted

  --odrd, --od-restoredefaultclocks
        Sets the core and memory clock to the default values.
        Warning X needs to be restarted before these clock changes will take
        effect

  --odcc, --od-commitclocks
        Once the stability of a new set of custom clocks has been proven this
        command will ensure that the Adapter will attempt to run at these new
        values whenever X is restarted
  --odgt, --od-gettemperature
        Returns the temperature reported by any thermal sensors available on
        the adapter.
```

So first you'll need to enable with

```
amdconfig --od-enable
```

then

```
amdconfig --odsc=coreclock,memclock
```

For example, I overlocked my ASUS 7850 by running: `amdconfig --odsc=950,1320` which is a 10% overclock.

Happy OCing!